# How can split a string with numbers in something like this |(12)|(23)

Tags: java, string, split

I have this string

```
String numbers = "123;234;345;"
```

and I need to convert it in a new string something like this:

```
String result= "|(123)|(234)|(345)"
```

I'm trying with this numbers.split("\("); but is not working, and I can't find any example of how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: is the result a single string, or does it show that the new numbers are just wrapped in brackets, or in a `|` aswell?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking here. Do you mean you want to parse string like `|(123)|(234)|(345)` into 3 integers?

Comment: I just edit my question, y have the string with "123;234;345;" and I need to split this string in another string like "|(123)|(234)|(345)". Hope that is more clear now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to split the string, just replace the semicolons, and put on a prefix and suffix:

```
String result = "|(" + numbers.replace(";", ")|(") + ")";
```

You can also do it using `split` as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : numbers.split(";")) {
  sb.append("|(");
  sb.append(str);
  sb.append(")");
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Note: the first approach doesn't handle the trailing `;` correctly. the second approach and @NicolasFilotto's answer do.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
String numbers = "123;234;345;";
String result = "|(" + numbers.replace(";", ")|(");
System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - 2));
```

The output is:

```
|(123)|(234)|(345)
```

Comment: Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`; regular expressions are not required here.